# default jekyll metadata setting?

Tags: jekyll

when I create the port on Jekyll admin

> title:  layout:
>    page comments: true
>    social-share: true
>    show-avatar:true
>   use_math: true

I want to create this as default how should I do it?

Answer (score 0):

Copy paste into your new post. Most CMS editors do that for you (like CloudCannon).

The real solution would be to transform them into site variables, by adding them to _config.yml and calling them using `{{ site.social-share }}` instead of `{{ page.social-share }}`.

An advanced solution would be to check if there are page variables, like this:

```
{% if page.social-share != nil %}
  {{ page.social-share }}
{% else %}
  {{ site.social-share }}
{% endif %}
```